Crossover design: relationship between differential carryover effect test and treatment effect test
I'm reading through this source, and there's a statement provided without reference:
"If the preliminary test for differential carryover is not significant, then the data from both periods are analyzed in the usual manner. Recent work, however, has revealed that this 2-stage analysis performs poorly because the unconditional Type I error rate operates at a much higher level than desired. We won't go into the specific details here, but part of the reason for this is that the test for differential carryover and the test for treatment differences in the first period are highly correlated and do not act independently."
Does anyone know where I can find more information on this (Yes, I've tried Googling around, but to no avail).
I'd like to know:

Why these two tests are correlated, and
How bad it would be to conduct a differential carryover test (confirming no carryover effect, hopefully!) before testing for a difference between treatment means (because if there's just a little correlation, then maybe it's not so bad? This seems to be a common practice, as evidenced here).


I am pretty sure Stephen Senn has written about this. I don't have my copy at hand, but I suspect his book on cross-over trials would have discussed the topic. If your study needs a carryover test, you've messed up. You normally do a cross-over study in a setting where with a sufficiently long washout, you are sure you can exclude the possibility of carryover. The issue with the two tests affecting each other, that's the case with almost all pre-tests (e.g. pre-testing for normality of residuals to decide between t-test vs. a rank test also leads to a type I error inflation).

Thanks, yes, I understand the idea of a washout period. Unfortunately, since I'm not doing a drug trial, a washout period is a bit odd to implement. Could you please provide some good resources for the pre-testing of normality of residuals that you mention? And yes, I think Stephen Senn did write about this, but textbook resources are hard to come by where I am. Do you have any recommended online resources?

There's a journal paper by Senn, too, which a simple search finds directly. The approach described is also listed as a common error here. Pre-test for normality discussed e.g. here or homegeneity of variance pre-test.
